# PHP curl google maps api return zero results while same url in browser returns

Tags: php, google-maps, curl

I am making a php curl request but as the title says it returns zero results while in browser it gives results, other zipcodes gives result in curl and also in browser.  (I took out the api key so it's able to test here, but same result with api key so I dont get You have exceeded your daily request but just empty array ).

Try url below in browser and curl call in https://onlinecurl.com/

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=4735CC,,&componentRestrictions=country:NL&sensor=false
```

full code:

```
gives result browser but not in curl
          //https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=4735CC,,&componentRestrictions=country:NL&sensor=false

gives result in curl & browser
        //https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=4751AJ,,&componentRestrictions=country:NL&sensor=false


            function getCoordinates($address, $zipcode, $city) {
                $location       = urlencode($address).','.urlencode($zipcode).','.urlencode($city);
                $details_url    = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=".$location;
                usleep(500000);

                $ch = curl_init();
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPGET,true);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $details_url);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
                $response   = json_decode(curl_exec($ch), true);
                var_dump($response);
 // gives {
   "results" : [],
   "status" : "ZERO_RESULTS"
}
```

Comment: I suggest to hide your apikey from the code

Comment: @ThomasV thx forgot

Comment: I get ZERO_RESULTS for that query (4735CC) from the browser.

Comment: @geocodezip because I have hidden my api key...

Comment: I tried it with an unrestricted key (and if the key is bad you get a different error)

Answer (score 2):

I think problem is with your input! Try this code, if you set only address / zipcode / city then it will works. May be Google maps not able to find combination of your input address + zipcode + city.

```
    function getCoordinates($address, $zipcode = null, $city = null ) {
        // $location       = urlencode($address).','.urlencode($zipcode).','.urlencode($city);
       $location = urlencode($address);
        $details_url    = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?key=key&address=".$location;
        usleep(500000);

        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPGET,true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $details_url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        $response   = json_decode(curl_exec($ch), true);
        var_dump($response); }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just got the same issue - maybe this IssueTracker link is helping you as much as it did for me. I needed to specify an "Accept-Language" header, which was automatically added for browser requests so Google could match the correct results.

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35822155